# How to split JSON into Dataset rows?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have the following JSON input data:

```
{
    "lib": [
      {
        "id": "a1",
        "type": "push",
        "icons": [
          {
            "iId": "111"
          }
        ],
        "id": "a2",
        "type": "pull",
        "icons": [
          {
            "iId": "111"
          },
          {
            "iId": "222"
          }
        ]
      }
]
```

I want to get the following Dataset:

```
id   type     iId
a1   push     111
a2   pull     111
a2   pull     222
```

How can I do it?

This is my current code. I use Spark 2.3 and Java 1.8:

```
ds = spark
         .read()
         .option("multiLine", true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
         .json(jsonFilePath);

ds = ds
        .select(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode(ds.col("lib.icons")).as("icons"));
```

However the result is wrong:

```
+---------------+
|          icons|
+---------------+
|        [[111]]|
|[[111], [222...|
+---------------+
```

How can I get the correct Dataset?

**UPDATE:**

I tries this code, but it generates some extra combinations of `id`, `type` and `iId` that do not exist in the input file.

```
ds = ds
      .withColumn("icons", org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode(ds.col("lib.icons")))
      .withColumn("id", org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode(ds.col("lib.id")))
      .withColumn("type", org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode(ds.col("lib.type")));

ds = ds.withColumn("its",  org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode(ds.col("icons")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON appears to be malformed. Fixing the indenting makes this slightly more apparent:

```
{
  "lib": [
    {
      "id": "a1",
      "type": "push",
      "icons": [
        {
          "iId": "111"
        }
      ],
      "id": "a2",
      "type": "pull",
      "icons": [
        {
          "iId": "111"
        },
        {
          "iId": "222"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Does your code work correctly if you feed it this JSON instead?

```
{
  "lib": [
    {
      "id": "a1",
      "type": "push",
      "icons": [
        {
          "iId": "111"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "a2",
      "type": "pull",
      "icons": [
        {
          "iId": "111"
        },
        {
          "iId": "222"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Note the inserted `}, {` just before `"id": "a2"` to break the object with duplicate keys into two, and the closing `}` at the very end which had previously been omitted.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, the JSON String seems to be malformed. with the updated one, you can use the following to get result you wanted:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

spark.read
      .format("json")
      .load("in/test.json")
      .select(explode($"lib").alias("result"))
      .select($"result.id", $"result.type", explode($"result.icons").alias("iId"))
      .select($"id", $"type", $"iId.iId")
      .show
```

Comment: I applied your code to the JSON file provided in the answer of @MTCoster, and got the following error `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "result.id" among (lib)`

Comment: Also, it only reads this JSON if I add `.option("multiLine", true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")` to Spark. Otherwise, it indicates that a record is corrupted.